# defrecord holding a incrementing `vector` / `java class`

Tags: clojure

Clojurians:
Thank you for your attention on this question !

Here is case I'm thinking about, I want to define a immutable bank account record

```
(defrecord account [ name balance statements])
(def cash-account (->account :cash 0.0 []))
```

I have a function that will `deposit` money to that account ,and a new record of `account` shall return

```
(.deposit cash-account 100.0 )
;; returns a new cash-account with attributes 
;; name = :cash balance= 100, statment=[ [(2018,1,1),100 ] ]
```

With more and more deposit and withdraw happening , the field `statement` list will expanding with more and more transactions inside.

My question will be : 
after 1000 transactions, there are 1000 elements in the `statment` field of latest account return.

When 1001th transaction happend:

will Clojure **copy** 1000 transactions in the `statment` field of old account record ,and append new transaction, save them into new account record ?

or Clojure just **append** the new transaction to the old account record and provide a new pointer to it , make it look like new account record like persistent map ?

Appreciate your help & many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://clojure.org/reference/datatypes#_deftype_and_defrecord :

- defrecord provides a complete implementation of a persistent map
- deftype supports mutable fields, defrecord does not

so, in your case, it will not *copy* the transactions, instead it will use a persistent data structure so it will look like the transaction was *appended*.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some more docs you should also check:

- https://www.braveclojure.com/functional-programming/
- https://clojure.org/guides/learn/sequential_colls
- https://purelyfunctional.tv/guide/clojure-collections/
- https://youtu.be/lJr6ot8jGQE